# How do I reference a custom .NET 4.0 DLL in script task?

Tags: dll, ssis, dts, gacutil

I would appreciate any help in referencing a DLL from my SSIS script task. I created the DLL in Visual Studio 2010 and the SSIS package in Business Inteligence Development Studio 2008. I am running on WinXP. The DLL compiles successfully and can be used in a windows forms application. Below are the steps I did to register the DLL in GAC but still got a warning on SSIS Script task stating the DLL is not visible thus useless.

1. Created key pair (sn -k ) in DLL project release folder.
2. Signed the DLL by right clicking the DLL project(on visual studio) > select properties > Sign tab.
3. Added the key pair.
4. Build the project.
5. Execute gacutil.exe (gacutil -i )

Below are my references(http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/niteshrai/archive/2010/04/13/referencing-an-assembly-inside-ssis-script-task.aspx)

I also read that SSIS in BIDS 2008 is not compatible with .Net framework 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010). Is their any truth in this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, BIDS 2008 supports only **`.NET Framework 3.5`** and not the *.NET Framework 4.0*. I would suggest that you compile your custom DLL to target .NET Framework 3.5, if you are not using .NET 4.0 functionality.

I have explained how to achieve this in a step-by-step example while answering the Stack Overflow question [**Why does SSIS fail to create this task?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691798/why-does-ssis-fail-to-create-this-task/6692304#6692304) The example builds a custom DLL in `VS 2010` but targets the `.NET Framework 2.0`.

Have a look at it. May be that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a com component using .net 2010 as cs file and deploy it and call this file using createobject in the script task.