# SSIS fails to create this task?

Tags: c#, ssis, task, toolbox

**UPDATE**:
After having restarted my BIDS, deleted my dll from GAC and task folder, and redoing the whole process, I was able to sort things out. So I don't know exactly what was wrong but that's something worth trying.

---

So I have exactly the same problem as here:
[Why does SSIS fail to create this task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691798/why-does-ssis-fail-to-create-this-task)

with the following task:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.IO;

namespace BloombergRequest
{
    [DtsTask(DisplayName= "BBG Request",
        Description= "A custom task for sending bloomberg requests",
        TaskContact = "BBG Request; OTC Fin Europe; Developed by N. Wadike - 2011.",
        TaskType= "Custom BBG task")]
    public class BBGRequest : Task
    {
        #region Constructors
        public BBGRequest()
        {
            //explode parameters into arrays and store in private fields
            _fields = Fields.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
            _headerOptions = HeaderOptions.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
            _headerValues = HeaderValues.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
            _securitiesValues = Securities.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
        }
        #endregion

        #region Override base methods

        public override DTSExecResult
            Execute(Connections connections,
            VariableDispenser variableDispenser,
            IDTSComponentEvents componentEvents,
            IDTSLogging log,
            object transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                SendRequest();
            }
            catch 
            {
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }

            return DTSExecResult.Success;
        }

        public override DTSExecResult Validate(
            Connections connections,
            VariableDispenser variableDispenser,
            IDTSComponentEvents componentEvents,
            IDTSLogging log)
        {...validate my inputs}

        #endregion

        #region Private methods

        private void SendRequest()
        {
            CreateHeader();
        }

        private void CreateHeader()
        {...do some stuff...}

        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public string Fields { get; set; }
        public string HeaderOptions { get; set; }
        public string HeaderValues { get; set; }
        public string OutputFolderPath { get; set; }
        public string Securities { get; set; }

        private string[] _fields;
        private string[] _headerOptions;
        private string[] _headerValues;
        private string[] _securitiesValues;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I followed the steps explained in the question linked above and it didn't solve my problem. This is my error:

```
===================================

Failed to create the task. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

===================================

Cannot create a task with the name "BloombergRequest.BBGRequest, BloombergRequest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c0c17a53adc44091". Verify that the name is correct.
 (BBG_REQ)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Executables.Add(String moniker)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.DtsBasePackageDesigner.CreateExecutable(String moniker, IDTSSequence container, String name)

===================================

Cannot create a task with the name "BloombergRequest.BBGRequest, BloombergRequest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c0c17a53adc44091". Verify that the name is correct.
 (BBG_REQ)

------------------------------
```

My project is called BloombergRequest, the class is BBGRequest...
I have checked and the dll is in GAC and I can add it to my toolbox in BIDS... But the error pops up when I try and drag it onto the designer....

Comment: It's a while since I did anything with SSIS but I think you need to have a signed copy of the DLL in a folder in \program files\sql server\dts\components (or similar; I'm going from memory here).

Comment: i followed this blog: http://grounding.co.za/blogs/brett/archive/2007/11/02/developing-a-custom-control-flow-task-for-ssis-part-8.aspx and i have a copy of the signed dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Tasks\. If not it wouldn't even appear in my toolbox.
ps: and yes it is signed if not it wouldn't show up in GAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having restarted my BIDS, deleted my dll from GAC and task folder, and redoing the whole process, I was able to sort things out. So I don't know exactly what was wrong but that's something worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted my dll from GAC and task folder, and recreate